# Ios multipart request not getting content type at server side

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby-on-rails, web-services, multipartform-data

I am doing small project in which I need to send image file to server for that I am using multipart request.

following is my code

```
UIImage *resizedImage1 = [img resizedImage:CGSizeMake(90.0f, 90.0f) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage1,0.8)];

    NSString *urlString = @"myUrl/accounts/add_profile_image";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
     NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

       // NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; image/jpeg; boundary=%@",boundary];

      NSString *accessToken=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userAccesstoken"];

    NSLog(@"access token %@",accessToken);
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    [request addValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth"];

    NSLog(@"request has %@",request);


   // NSLog(@"imagedata has %@",imageData);

    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];


        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

         // parameter v=1000
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"v\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1000\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // mz_access_token sewt token parameter
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mz_access_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",accessToken]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // image data parameter
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    **[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];**
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [postbody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




     NSLog(@"body has %@",postbody);
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

        // set the content-length
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postbody length]];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

    NSError *errorReturned = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];


    //check netwrok

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&theResponse
                                                     error:&errorReturned];

    if(data)
    {
        //parsing json
        // again converting into ns dictionary object

        NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
        //NSLog(@"post data %@",postbody);
       // NSLog(@"response of web ser %@ :\n %@",name,jsonArray);

        NSLog(@"Response data %@",jsonArray);

//        return jsonArray;

    }else{
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    }
//    return [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    });
```

This is my web service request.
I am setting content type like

```
 [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but still at server side I am getting **@content-type =nill**
**At server side we used ROR for `webservice`**

Please help me to solve this.
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting content type by header parameters as

```
[request setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Please make the change.

Comment: Tried with the above answer but its given me the same result.It does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

For every multipart/form element, you need to set a proper `Content-Type`, e.g. the following for text-parameters:

```
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```